# Func with generic class parameter and casting

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have `Func<>` that have generic class as input parameter. The question is how to cast it to similar Func but with class that have parameter derived from previous? For now below code give me null in fu2.

```
var fu = new Func<Envelope<Base>, object>(Simple);
var fu2 = fu as Func<Envelope<Derived>, object>;

public class Envelope<T>
{
    public T Enveloped { get; set; }
}
public class Base
{

}
public class Derived: Base
{

}
```

Comment: "fu2" seems ill-named, though fortunately the C# compiler has thick skin. That said, you can't do what you're trying to do. `Envelope<Derived>` isn't in any sense a subclass of `Envelope<Base>`; it's an unrelated class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Func<T, object>` is contravariant in `T` so

```
var fu2 = fu as Func<Envelope<Derived>, object>;
```

will succeed if `Envelope<Derived>` is a subtype of `Envelope<Base>`. Classes are invariant but you can define an interface:

```
public interface IEnvelope<out T>
{
    T Enveloped { get; }
}
```

and have `Envelope<T>` implement it. Then the following will compile:

```
Func<IEnvelope<Base>, object> fu = null;
Func<IEnvelope<Derived>, object> fu2 = fu;
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting a generic expression does not work, because there is no covariance among lambda expressions.

However, you can make an expression that constructs a new `Envelope<Base>`, and wraps the enveloped derived object into it, like this:

```
var fu = new Func<Envelope<Base>,object>(Simple);
Func<Envelope<Derived>,object> fu2 = x => fu(new Envelope<Base> {Enveloped = x.Enveloped});
```

The new expression calls `fu` with `new Envelope<Base> {Enveloped = x.Enveloped}` parameter, which is an envelope of a compatible type constructed from the parameter of the `fu2` expression.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/bVBMAs)